# What's the absolute cheapest way of bringing a car from USA to UK using a UK bound ship/tanker etc?

Tags: usa, automobiles, shipping

I'm looking to import an old american car to England and wondered if there is an even cheaper perhaps unofficial way other than using a regular Roll On - Roll Off shipping service? I'm thinking of a boat/ship that might be capable of carrying one or two vehicles.

Comment: You might get better help at [expatriates.se].

Comment: Why would you use a Ro/Ro?  You just put it in a container.

Comment: Unfortunately shipping questions are off-topic for this site.